# Are we allowed to vote on our own answers?

Tags: support, voting, up-votes

I was wondering. If I tried to vote my own answer up, would that be allowed?

Comment: The system does not allow it.

Comment: @T.Bongers maybe the help center should be edited to reflect that.

Comment: Is not the message you get when you try to vote on your own answer sufficient?

Comment: In case you're for some reason afraid to try it yourself, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Scy7L.png) is what you will see.

Comment: @Arthur: Why the blur?

Comment: @Asaf: It helps you focus.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I never tried it. I asked instead.

Comment: Can you downvote your own answer?  (I believe that Georg Kreisel once wrote a severely critical Zentrablatt review of one of his own papers.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on what moderator Alexander Gruber said: No you are not allowed to vote on your own post. In fact, if you try to vote on your own post, then you will get an error message saying: "You can't vote for your own post".

The only way to vote for your own post is to have more than one account and use one account to vote for posts from the other. While it is not illegal to have multiple accounts, you are in no way allowed to have two accounts interact with each other. In particular you are not allowed to use one account to vote on posts made by the other account. The moderators have ways to figure out if this type of behavior takes place and I am sure that they will take prompt action.

Comment: Well, you don't need _several_ accounts to upvote your own posts: two would suffice.  But, yes, the ♦-mods may notice this, and then we'll have a small chat with the miscreant which will have three outcomes: (1) the main account will be put on a timed suspension; (2) the voting sockpuppets will be deleted; and (3) any ill-gotten reputation will be invalidated.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: I changed the several to more than one. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

No.

Comment: And, furthermore, the second-best solution (of voting all the other answers down) should also be avoided.  If the other answers are all so bad, explain that in comments.

Answer (score 5):

[image]